# Linux, C++, setting a memory limit for a subprocess

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I have an application that forks a process using fork() functions.

I want to be able to limit the amount of memory available to this process (if I cant limit it, then segkilling it when it reaches will also do).

What are my options in Linux?
I know about [setrlimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), is there anything else?

(Note: I want a purely C/C++ solution, i.e external scripts etc.. are not an option)

Comment: There are in-kernel cgroups with resource limits and kludge of external scripts/programs to monitor subprocess resource usage and kill it, for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44988 "pshved/timeout" (description http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40).

Comment: I want a purely c++ solution, I,e external scripts aren't really an option, does cgroups have an API?

Comment: Joe, you can do the same as in the pshved/timeout script with C/C++. cgroups is kernel API: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-resources-using-cgroups-on-centos-6 "memory — this subsystem sets limits on memory use by tasks in a cgroup and generates automatic reports on memory resources used by those tasks" - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-memory.html https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt; lib - http://libcg.sourceforge.net/; concept https://lwn.net/Articles/236038/

Comment: `setrlimit()` is the standard way to do this.  But you already know about it.  So what are you actually asking?

Comment: the problem with setrlimit() is that you don't know, if the child terminated because it run of memory or  due to an unhandled exception, etc..